# MySQL - Indexing for String Comparison

Tags: mysql, indexing

This is for InnoDB with MySQL 5.7.

If I have a query like:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE STRCMP(D, 'somestring') > 0
```

Is it possible to have an index on `D` which can be used by the query? i.e. is MySQL smart enough to use the btree index for STRCMP function?

If not, how might I be able to redesign the query (and/or table) such that I can do string comparison on D, and there can be some form of pruning so that it does not have to hit every single row?

Comment: use : WHERE D like %somestring%

Comment: @kollein: I'm sorry, but how is this comment even relevant? Firstly, with %somestring%, because of variable prefix, indexing is off. Secondly, I'm trying to do string comparison, not substring matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazing how many wrong answers so far.  Let me see if I can not join them.

`STRCMP` returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on how the arguments compare.

`STRCMP(D, 'somestring') > 0` is identical to `D > 'somestring'`.  (Not `>=`, not `=`, not `LIKE`)

Actually, there *may* be collation differences, but that can be handled if necessary.

Any function, and certain operators, 'hide' columns from use with `INDEXes`.  `D > 'somestring'` can benefit from an index starting with `D`; the `STRCMP` version cannot.

Comment: Thanks @rick-james! (And also to @ydoow and @mike-bryant). This may sound silly, but I didn't know that ">", etc can be used on strings operands!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
WHERE D > 'somestring'
```

This would leverage a typical B-tree index on column `D`.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform comparisons only by passing column values to a function such as `STRCMP()`, there is no value in indexing it.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the `=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, or `BETWEEN` operators.

So, you may use

`SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE D > 'somestring'`

instead, while `LIKE` is more strict and could be what you expect.

Also, you can use the `COLLATE` operator to convert the column to a case-sensitive collation, to make sure it's comparing the case as well.

`SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE D > 'somestring' COLLATE utf8_bin`

Comment: `LIKE` without a wildcard character is the same as `=`.  I think the OP's intent was as a sorting mechanism of sorts - return all records where D is greater than (in alphanumeric sorting terms) the string against which the table records are being compared.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrant for pointing that out. I've overlooked the question and got it wrong. Corrected answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql will not use indexes for function calls.

Use below query And Create index on **D** column

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE D ='somestring'
```

to create index use the below query

```
 create index index1 on TABLE(D);
```